# Raw H264 to JPEG, in C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, jpeg, h.264

I get a stream of frames, an initial SPS and PPS h264 data packet and then packets for the I and P frames.

Using c# .NET I want to convert into a series of JPEGs? Has anyone done this? 
I have tried AForge.NET FFMpeg wrapper, but can only go from MP4 file to JPEGs?
Also looked at DirectShow.

I can't seem to find an examples that even come close to doing this?

Thanks

Comment: So you're getting a h264 stream and you want to convert each frame to a jpeg?

Comment: Hi, yes, so I get a series of raw h264 data frames (SPS and PPS first) then the I and P frames. It is someones elses code and it can save some parts to mp4 files as required, but I need to add decoding of each frame to a still frame, JPEG, (bitmap in C#), which may be saved to disc or discarded.

Answer (score 0):

In Directshow, it sounds like you need to introduce a SampleGrabber filter into your filter graph.  Insert this after the H264 decoder.

This is a pass through filter which can receive a callback containing each video frame.  You can then obviously choose what you do with the frame, is save it to disk as a jpeg etc.

Rather than regurgitate MSDN, there is a great page explaining its usage here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407288(v=vs.85).aspx

Update taking account of Roman's comments:

SampleGrabber is deprecated as its part of Directshow Editing Services.  However, it is quite self contained.  If it was removed from a later version of Windows it would be straight forward to  replace with an alternative filter.  I still use it in one of my consumer applications.  Roman is correct though - it has a steep learning curve.

Comment: Sample Grabber is deprecated because it is a part of DirectShow Editing Services. DirectShow itself is not deprecated and remains in good standing. Documentation is pretty accurate on this. Also, as a side note, it is possible to even compress to JPEGs with stock DirectShow filter the way you mentioned. C# developer would hate to use DirectShow for this, but it's the price to pay for H.264 video decoder: somehow it has to be used and it is not available in very simple for factor. It is possible to use Media Foundation H.264 decoder, however it is not going to be easy anyway.